# Bulk granular weed killer for dandelions in NW Ohio?

Tags: grass, weed-control, weeds, yard

**Explanation:**

I have around 5 acres of grass that is quickly being overtaken by dandelions.  In years past, I've used liquid broadleaf killer to knock them down, and it's done a pretty good job.

But I've since planted around 30 trees in and around the area. Due to the almost non-stop wind in my area, I'm very hesitant to use any liquid spray now for concern of killing the trees.

I have a tow-behind spreader I could use for granular weed killer, but all I can find is Weed and Feed, which looks like it'd cost around $500 for a single application (ouch!)

**Question:**

Is there a granular weed killer I can buy without paying extra for the "feed" portion?  Even if I can't get it from a big box store, if there was something I should use, I can call the local farm supply companies to see if they have whatever is recommended.

Comment: The use of herbicides has different laws in every place.  I can't buy or use some herbicides unless I am a licensed applicator or a farmer. I think answers for this will be very localized so we may have to close unless you want to edit  the question to focus on how to control the dandelions

Comment: @kevinskio - updated.  That work?

Comment: lets see what answers you get